# How to implement version tracking of documents in a GUI editor

Tags: java, version-control

I'm in the middle of a java project in swing. I've already made a GUI editor in which you can load, edit through the GUI and save on the system's disk. I came to this user story and don't really know how to approach it. It seems like a git for documents?

> As a user, I should be able to activate an automatic version tracking mechanism that keeps track of the document evolution history, at any time. The history consists of a sequence of subsequent versions of the Latex document. The mechanism should provide at least two alternative storage strategies for the document evolution history:
>
> - Volatile (default strategy): for each document change the mechanism keeps the previous version of the document in a main memory list of subsequent document versions.
> - Stable: for each document change the mechanism keeps the previous version of the
>     document on disk storage.

I'm thinking the volatile strategy is saving current progress in a string? Should every time the JTextArea of the GUI is edited the string be updated?

Answer (score 0):

It actually seems like the UNDO action most editors provide, but with a different "version handling" process.

In order to implement Volatile strategy (as described), i would use a data structure to keep the versions of the document. For example, a `HashMap<Integer, Document>` which keeps the versions of the document as keys, and document clones as values. So whenever i want to go to a previous version, i just do it like:

```
private void goToPreviousVersion(Document doc)
{
    Document oldVersion = hashmap.get(doc.getVersionId());
    doc.setContent(oldVersion);
    //copy all properties from old version the the document

    //Update the view (GUI)
}
```

Now saving a version should be easy. Something like:

```
private void saveVersion(Document doc)
{
    hashmap.put(doc.getVersionId(), doc.clone());
    doc.setVersionId(doc.getVersionId +1);
}
```

Kind of the same applies to Stable strategy, but instead of having a data structure, you save the clones in hard disk with names you can search later in order to go back. For example, version1, version2, version3, etc.. When you want to go back, simple load the file "version"+(document.getVersionId-1).

---

About changing the version strategy at any time, it is easy. Create classes that represent these version mechanisms (e.g VolatileStrategy, StableStrategy) and add a relation to them. Can be done via a parent class (`VolatileStrategy extends VersionStrategy`) or maybe an interface (something i would prefer) like `VolatileStrategy implements VersionStrategy`. Finally, keep a reference of the active strategy, `private VersionStrategy versionStrategy;` and whenever you want to change it, simply:
`versionStrategy = new StableStrategy();`

---

Saving the versions could be done with many ways. One way, simple one, is to add a button to your GUI, named like "Keep Version". When it is clicked, a version of the document is kept. Another way, and most common in all editors (but more complex to implement), is with a timer.

When a key is pressed into the text field, the timer starts, let's say for 300ms. If another key is pressed before the 300ms, the timer restarts. If nothing is pressed within 300 ms the timer saves the version of the document and stops. Then, during next key press, the timer starts over and this process is being repeated.

In case you are interested in to implement the second way, but you have never worked with Swing timers before, take a look at [How to use timers in swing.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)